# Reset ng-view top position to 0 when change route

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

i made a transition page, when rout change the animation not work fine.

The animation type is from bottom to top, you can see in the first load page.

How can I fix ?

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/j7r3s33Y3GcTyH2Fop9K?p=preview

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider.
    when("/first-page", {
      templateUrl: "first-page.html",
      animate: "slideup"
    }).
    when("/second-page", {
      templateUrl: "second-page.html",
      animate: "slideup"
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/first-page"
    });

});


// PAGE ANIMATE DIRECTIVE
app.directive('animClass',function($route){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
      var enterClass = $route.current.animate;
      elm.addClass(enterClass)
      scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
        elm.removeClass(enterClass)
        elm.addClass($route.current.animate)
      })
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: add window.offsetTop=0 in $locationChangeStart event?

Comment: works fine, great :D